# Parsing a property file content to HTML

Tags: file, properties

I have a property file( actually 100 or more). This is actually placed in one of the configuration folder so usually not been able to modify very often. So now we came up with an idea that the property file is parsed read and converted into meaningful HTML page .For

```
example :
forecast.allow.pattern.overrides = N.
```

This property has 2 possible values Y or N . So this can be a radio button. 
Again

```
forecast.config.path = forecast
```

This should be a read only attribute since this shouldn't be modified .
I need help here on how we need to decide a property can be converted to radio button or list box etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide that if the value is "Y" or "N", then it probably is a check box.

For other text values, I don't think you can decide if the value is part of an enumeration (which would lead to a combo box) or not (which would lead to a text input) or even if it's read-only (which would lead to a simple label).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a second property file for each existing property file. The second one records the type of each property (check, combo, readonly, etc.).